# Meaning of breath off in a razor'

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Is 'breath off in a razor' an idiom?
I saw it from a book, which goes like this.

> When all of a sudden he was paralyzed into a listening attitude and that smile faded gradually out of his countenance like ***breath off'n a razor***,and the queerest look of surprise took its place.

<sup>Source: Mark Twain, A Tramp Abroad</sup>

Comment: If you breathe upon a razor's blade, moisture from your breath will precipitate on it, making it opaque, but it will soon start to evaporate, turning it "clear" and mirrorlike again. It is not a stock expression or idiom but a simile coined by the author, possibly to facilitate suspence, since razor blades are used not only for shaving.

Comment: Looks like the answer to me @CopperKettle

Comment: Note that *off'n* is dialect for *off of*, not *off in*. And this was written in the 19th century, before the advent of safety razors, so what Twain has in mind is something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/No_name_straight_razor.JPG).

Answer (score 5):

If you breathe upon a razor's blade, moisture from your breath will precipitate on it, making it opaque, but it will soon start to evaporate, turning it clear and mirrorlike again. It is not a stock expression or idiom but a simile coined by the author.

Thus, to simplify,

> The character's smile faded out of his countenance just like a layer of mist fades from a razor's blade.

Notice how people sometimes make knives and spoons shiny or lenses more transparent by first breathing on them in order to moisten them, then wiping them with a clean cloth.